# How many cups is 8 whole peaches equivalent to?

Tags: recipe-scaling, peaches

I have some fresh peaches that have been peeled and sliced and mixed with some sugar and a little lemon (approx 1/2 a bushel).

All the recipes I can find only call for  "8 peaches" or similar values. But my peaches are already cut up.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how many cups of peaches is equivalent to 8 peaches?

Comment: If there hasn't been too much sugar added to 'em -- make peach butter, and then can the extras.  If you have people to help you eat it, make cobbler.  If you want some extra variety, search for a recipe called 'Peach Enchiladas' (and then use Mt. Dew when making it).

Answer (score 5):

If I gave you *any* number I'd be almost certainly wrong - peaches come in many different sizes. (And personally I'm led to believe that any recipe that gives only a number like "8 peaches" is either crap because is's imprecise or tolerates a lot of difference.)

So I suggest you

- **either find a recipe with a weight**
  My first guess is jams that often use equal or specific-ratio parts (by weight) of ingredients.
- **or one that gives volumetric meassurement for the *cut* fruit**
  "add two cups of sliced peaches"
- **or choose something that can be imprecise because you add ingredients to taste.**
  Compote, for example. Less sugar for ripe fruit, more for tart ones...

And if all fails and you have only sliced your fruit, try to "build" a whole peach (sort of, you don't have to find the original pieces, this isn't CSI) and weigh that. The rest is simple math. If you want to be very precise you could weigh 1c sugar as well and subtract from the total amount, but for 1/2 bushel of fruit I'd probably ignore it.

Comment: Cobbler. OMG cobbler... or pie.... or even just "pie filling". So good.

Comment: @Catija Yup. All out of the third category, methinks ^_^

Answer (score 4):

As they say in the US state of Maine "*You can't get there from here.*"

You need to know the peach size before you cleaned an syrup'd them.

I checked [USDA Table 8](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2311?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=50&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=peaches&ds=Standard%20Reference&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), it has nutrition, volume and weight information, and found:

[image]

> Does anyone have a suggestion as to how many cups of peaches is equivalent to 8 peaches?

Based on the chart above, here is my guesstimate:

- the recipe is written for medium peaches (150 grams each) [*medium is an assumption*]
- 8 peaches times 150 grams = 1200 grams of peach needed
- 1200 grams of peaches / 154 grams for a measuring cup gives, **just under 8 cups of peaches = 8 medium peaches**

As you can see, there's allot of wiggle room in there. Consider keeping notes while cooking with goal of writing your own future recipe in grams.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that 2 medium size peaches is a cup, give or take, and this works in a recipe I like that calls for 8 peaches.

Comment: I've removed the rant-ish parts here, to leave behind the actual answer to the question. It's best to focus on answering the question, and if you must disagree with something else, to just explain why, and avoid inflammatory language.

Comment: -1, because in every locale I have ever lived, "medium size peach" was a very different thing from the "medium size" in the next locale. "Very different" as in, the largest "average peach" I've seen must have a volume of about 6-8 times as much as the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the size of the peach.
You don't say what you're making but I would suggest, adding a small amount of peaches at a time to whatever you're making, see if it looks like enough ,add more, make sure you add a small amount at a time, you may not be able to remove but you can always add more.
Make sure you measure the amount you add so if you like the outcome, you can make it again.

Answer (score 0):

8 peaches equal five and a half to 6 cups of sliced peaches

Comment: ...depending on size, rotten parts discarded, ...